# Why is my boiler intermittently shutting off?

Tags: boiler

I have a Burnham boiler model `pvg8ani-gs`.

It shuts off for no obvious reason. It might run for 1 minute or 30 seconds and then might stay running.

I have replaced the board and it still has the same problem. No faults so up it goes 1 7 8 then goes to self check 17.

Any ideas what could be causing the problem?

I want to replace the wire harness next but can't find it...

Comment: Nothing happens for "no reason". We just don't know what it is yet.  Doubt if it's the wiring harness, probably a bad sensor, like a flame proving sensor, over temp, etc. Don't just throw parts at it. Figure out what self check 17 means. Also, I have no idea what you mean by "No faults so it goes up 1 7 8 then ..."

Comment: Can you clarify what, "No faults so up it goes 1 7 8 then goes to self check 17." means? Is that something that appears on a diagnostic display on the front panel, or...? Also, I removed the "where to buy" part of the question - shopping recommendations are explicitly off topic.